# Is it possible to include several header files that define complex structs with same names?

Tags: c++, struct, include, header-files, redefinition

So I have several autogenerated files, each defines a complex struct with a unique name. They consists of some primitive types and structs.

Here is a little scheme of that two files. One `car.h` and one `bike.h`, each file defines the same struct called `Coordinates`. But when I try to compile I get redefinition errors.

Is it possible to include that header files both? Or do I have to merge them into one header?

```
car.h
#ifndef CAR_H_
#define CAR_H_

#pragma pack(push,4)
typedef struct
{
    uint32 pos_x;
    uint32 pos_y
} Coordinates;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct
{
    tUInt8 id;
    Coodinates position_of_car;
} Car;
#pragma pack(pop)
[...]
```

Bike.h defines `Coordinates` as well.

```
bike.h
#ifndef BIKE_H_
#define BIKE_H_

#pragma pack(push,4)
typedef struct
{
    uint32 pos_x;
    uint32 pos_y
} Coordinates;
#pragma pack(pop)

#pragma pack(push,1)
typedef struct
{
    uint8 id;
    Coodinates position_of_car;
} Bike;
#pragma pack(pop)
[...]
```

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

Comment: Not your problem, but you have tagged this C++.  `typedef struct { ... } Foo` would be much better as `struct Foo { ... };`  (Even in C you can, and probably should, write `typedef struct Foo { ... } Foo;` - that way you can refer to `struct Foo` without the #include.)

Comment: May be that's more a problem how the generator is fed. I suspect you use some kind of data structure scheme and defined `Coordinates` locally for `Car` and `Bike`, while this structure should be shared by both.

Comment: The generator is fed with one header. I am just selecting `Car` and `Bike` to extract them into an own header with their dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely to cause a redefinition error.
I would advise to put the Coordinates structure in its own header file (with protection against multiple inclusion) and include it from Car.h and Bike.h

Comment: The files are auto-generated. It is not clear whether OP can just put the structures in their own header.

Comment: Putting them in an own header would be possible. But the two structs Car and Bike are just for illustration. The productive headers and structs are more complex and I would not benefit with this solution.